# Remote weblogic EAR deploy using jenkins plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, weblogic

I am in a sitauation where I have build maven build EAR files and property files which are needed to be deployed on QA remote weblogic hotel instances.

I have build code using maven in jenkins and also have weblogic deployer plugin installed.

But not able to find clear steps on how to configure it to deploy to remote weblogic servers where I don't have admin server rights .

My ears files have project version in name so at times when name change then in weblogic it need to undeploy and deploy with restart how can I achive it using jenkins.

Any help is appeciated( I have gone through [post](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin)) but I don't have weblogic.jar in my Jenkins server as in my case it is remote server with shared folder with Ear deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Your weblogic.jar needs to be on the jenkins server somehow. You can upload it to the server and refer to it with a static path, or possibly check it into your SCM and reference it from the workspace of your job (May violate licensing if your SCM repository is public).

Comment: I have found the weblogic .jar in the wls installation of jenkins and added in "Additinal Class path" filed "C:\Oracle\MIDDLEWARE\wlserver_10.3\server\lib" i am not clear how about configuration file  description given in 
-https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin ,, as i dont know how to create user store key etc ?Also as  my diff jobs will deploy to diff weblogic instance this approch wont work for all jobs to use this plugin than as each will have diff credentials .

Comment: Hi,
You need user store only if you are secured weblogic admin with a keystore. If not left it blank.

weblogic.jar path has to be configured under global Jenkins configuration.

About some diff deployment to diff WL instance with diff credential, you just need to configure all of your target into the configuration file set in the global Jenkins configuration.

Then foreach each deployment task select the right target.

Regards.